# Create a QAQC flag column based on non consecutive values for binary character column

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am working with a time series data frame that contains a column of measured values, and another character column that classifies the value based on whether it falls above or below a certain threshold. In the example below, values above 300 are assigned "class a" while values below 300 are "class b". I would like to create another column that identifies instances where a "class a" observation is surrounded on both sides by by x number of "class b" observations, or vise versa, for the purpose of identifying suspect points. Here is the data frame described above:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Make reproducible data frame:

# Generate datetime
datetime <- seq(lubridate::ymd_hm("2015-1-1 0:00"), lubridate::ymd_hm("2015-2-1 12:00"), by = "hour")

# Generate measured value
value <- runif(n = 757, min = 100, max = 1000)

# Make data frame
df <- data.frame(datetime, value)

# Make the classification column that classifies value based on absolute numerical threshold
df <- df %>%
  mutate(classification = dplyr::if_else(value >= 300, "class a", "class b"))
```

The actual data I am working with is much longer. But say for this example, how could I create a new column that identifies when a "class a" observation is surrounded on both sides by at least 10 consecutive "class b" observations or if a "class b" observation is surrounded on both sides by at least 10 consecutive "class a" observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rleid` function on `data.table` library  to grouping on non consecutive data, then count it and check if the previous and next rows have more than 10 consecutive values. Here is an example.

**PD** i modified the "min" value in `runif` to made the example more prone to find a positive case, and added `set.seed(1234)` to made `runif` reproducible.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#Make reproducible data frame:
set.seed(1234)
# Generate datetime
datetime <- seq(lubridate::ymd_hm("2015-1-1 0:00"), lubridate::ymd_hm("2015-2-1 12:00"), by = "hour")

# Generate measured value
value <- runif(n = 757, min = 280, max = 1000)

# Make data frame
df <- data.frame(datetime, value)

# Make the classification column that classifies value based on absolute numerical threshold
df <- df %>%
  mutate(classification = dplyr::if_else(value >= 300, "class a", "class b"))



df<-group_by(df, data.table::rleid(classification)) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(QAQC =  classification!=lag(classification,1,default="") 
                     & classification != lead(classification,1, default = "") 
                     & lag(n,1, default = 0) > 10 & lead(n,1,default=0)>10)

print(df , n = 120)
#> # A tibble: 757 × 6
#>     datetime            value classification rleid(classificatio…¹     n QAQC
#>     <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>                          <int> <int> <lgl>  
#>   1 2015-01-01 00:00:00  362. class a                            1     6 FALSE  
#>   2 2015-01-01 01:00:00  728. class a                            1     6 FALSE  
#>   3 2015-01-01 02:00:00  719. class a                            1     6 FALSE  
#>   4 2015-01-01 03:00:00  729. class a                            1     6 FALSE  
#>   5 2015-01-01 04:00:00  900. class a                            1     6 FALSE  
#>   6 2015-01-01 05:00:00  741. class a                            1     6 FALSE  
#>   7 2015-01-01 06:00:00  287. class b                            2     1 FALSE  
#>   8 2015-01-01 07:00:00  447. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>   9 2015-01-01 08:00:00  760. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  10 2015-01-01 09:00:00  650. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  11 2015-01-01 10:00:00  779. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  12 2015-01-01 11:00:00  672. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  13 2015-01-01 12:00:00  484. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  14 2015-01-01 13:00:00  945. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  15 2015-01-01 14:00:00  490. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  16 2015-01-01 15:00:00  883. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  17 2015-01-01 16:00:00  486. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  18 2015-01-01 17:00:00  472. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  19 2015-01-01 18:00:00  414. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  20 2015-01-01 19:00:00  447. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  21 2015-01-01 20:00:00  508. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  22 2015-01-01 21:00:00  498. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  23 2015-01-01 22:00:00  395. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  24 2015-01-01 23:00:00  309. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  25 2015-01-02 00:00:00  438. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  26 2015-01-02 01:00:00  864. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  27 2015-01-02 02:00:00  659. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  28 2015-01-02 03:00:00  939. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  29 2015-01-02 04:00:00  879. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  30 2015-01-02 05:00:00  313. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  31 2015-01-02 06:00:00  608. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  32 2015-01-02 07:00:00  471. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  33 2015-01-02 08:00:00  499. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  34 2015-01-02 09:00:00  645. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  35 2015-01-02 10:00:00  410. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  36 2015-01-02 11:00:00  827. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  37 2015-01-02 12:00:00  425. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  38 2015-01-02 13:00:00  466. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  39 2015-01-02 14:00:00  994. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  40 2015-01-02 15:00:00  861. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  41 2015-01-02 16:00:00  678. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  42 2015-01-02 17:00:00  745. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  43 2015-01-02 18:00:00  505. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  44 2015-01-02 19:00:00  728. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  45 2015-01-02 20:00:00  517. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  46 2015-01-02 21:00:00  641. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  47 2015-01-02 22:00:00  768. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  48 2015-01-02 23:00:00  629. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  49 2015-01-03 00:00:00  456. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  50 2015-01-03 01:00:00  831. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  51 2015-01-03 02:00:00  333. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  52 2015-01-03 03:00:00  503. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  53 2015-01-03 04:00:00  796. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  54 2015-01-03 05:00:00  643. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  55 2015-01-03 06:00:00  390. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  56 2015-01-03 07:00:00  643. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  57 2015-01-03 08:00:00  636. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  58 2015-01-03 09:00:00  821. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  59 2015-01-03 10:00:00  406. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  60 2015-01-03 11:00:00  891. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  61 2015-01-03 12:00:00  903. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  62 2015-01-03 13:00:00  310. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  63 2015-01-03 14:00:00  508. class a                            3    56 FALSE  
#>  64 2015-01-03 15:00:00  290. class b                            4     1 FALSE  
#>  65 2015-01-03 16:00:00  452. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  66 2015-01-03 17:00:00  789. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  67 2015-01-03 18:00:00  502. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  68 2015-01-03 19:00:00  646. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  69 2015-01-03 20:00:00  317. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  70 2015-01-03 21:00:00  686. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  71 2015-01-03 22:00:00  367. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  72 2015-01-03 23:00:00  923. class a                            5     8 FALSE  
#>  73 2015-01-04 00:00:00  291. class b                            6     1 FALSE  
#>  74 2015-01-04 01:00:00  844. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  75 2015-01-04 02:00:00  345. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  76 2015-01-04 03:00:00  654. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  77 2015-01-04 04:00:00  557. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  78 2015-01-04 05:00:00  330. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  79 2015-01-04 06:00:00  511. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  80 2015-01-04 07:00:00  761. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  81 2015-01-04 08:00:00  947. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  82 2015-01-04 09:00:00  620. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  83 2015-01-04 10:00:00  383. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  84 2015-01-04 11:00:00  672. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  85 2015-01-04 12:00:00  421. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  86 2015-01-04 13:00:00  927. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  87 2015-01-04 14:00:00  560. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  88 2015-01-04 15:00:00  504. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  89 2015-01-04 16:00:00  395. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  90 2015-01-04 17:00:00  925. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  91 2015-01-04 18:00:00  400. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  92 2015-01-04 19:00:00  928. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  93 2015-01-04 20:00:00  377. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  94 2015-01-04 21:00:00  375. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  95 2015-01-04 22:00:00  356. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  96 2015-01-04 23:00:00  648. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  97 2015-01-05 00:00:00  496. class a                            7    24 FALSE  
#>  98 2015-01-05 01:00:00  299. class b                            8     1 TRUE   
#>  99 2015-01-05 02:00:00  503. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 100 2015-01-05 03:00:00  814. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 101 2015-01-05 04:00:00  306. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 102 2015-01-05 05:00:00  687. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 103 2015-01-05 06:00:00  482. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 104 2015-01-05 07:00:00  427. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 105 2015-01-05 08:00:00  376. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 106 2015-01-05 09:00:00  514. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 107 2015-01-05 10:00:00  392. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 108 2015-01-05 11:00:00  374. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 109 2015-01-05 12:00:00  594. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 110 2015-01-05 13:00:00  308. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 111 2015-01-05 14:00:00  794. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 112 2015-01-05 15:00:00  353. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 113 2015-01-05 16:00:00  964. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 114 2015-01-05 17:00:00  368. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 115 2015-01-05 18:00:00  438. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 116 2015-01-05 19:00:00  937. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 117 2015-01-05 20:00:00  961. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 118 2015-01-05 21:00:00  481. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 119 2015-01-05 22:00:00  369. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> 120 2015-01-05 23:00:00  854. class a                            9    87 FALSE  
#> # … with 637 more rows, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   ¹​`rleid(classification)`
```